# Relational operator in C while using real variables

Tags: c, floating-point, relational

Why the output is not as expected?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    float a,b,c;
    b=0.7;
    if( b<0.7 )
        printf(" It should NOT be here");
    else
        printf("It Should be here");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and give the expected output, and what you get as output as well.

Answer (score 0):

0.7 is double value. Try 0.7f in code. It should work.

Comment: No, seems You don't understand floating point behaviours. Is 0.69999999999999996 or 0.699999988 depends on declaration

Comment: b is a float; 0.7 is a value of type double.  The comparison between the two requires a conversion. The compiler will convert the float value to a double value ... and the value resulting from converting a float to a double is not the same as the value resulting from the compiler converting a string of text (the source code) to a double.  But don't ever compare floating point values (float, double, or long double) with ==.

Comment: @JacekCz - I tried this code with 0.7f and it works. Please try by yourself. It should work.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis but type should be same. Float should be compared with float.

Comment: @Jaczek: If the conversion is correct, the value in `b` should be equal to `0.7f`: `b = 0.7f; if (b < 0.7f)`.

Comment: @Ganeshdip: I misunderstood your comment, sorry. You answer is a little short, but correct.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's ok :)

Answer (score -1):

Floating point numbers

- have limited accuracy
- some value doesn't exist. `0.7` is such value. On my platform is
  `0.699999988`. 
  Reason: we write numbers as decimal, but internal are realised as binary. Many longer materials exist 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

So behaviour You are surprised

Comment: FWIW, `0.7` (double) is exactly `0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`, while `0.7f` (float) is exactly `0.699999988079071044921875`. So the float is slightly smaller than the *double* representation of `0.7`.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try the below Code, it works!!!:

**Code**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int  main(void)
    {

    float a,b,c,temp;
    temp=0.7;
    b=0.7;

    if( b<temp )
        printf(" It should NOT be here");
    else
        printf("It Should be here");


    }
```

Comment: And did You try? Probably not

Comment: it works!! i have run it

Comment: Serious? On which platform?

Comment: Changing assignment for initialization doesn't change a thing. This is a platform dependent result that has to do with how floating point works. You just gave the OP their own code and said "try it".

Comment: linux and windows.

Comment: in linux the code of OP, give the variables the below values:a=0.0,b=0.0,c=0.7.thats why i gave this declaration:double  a=0.7, b=0.7, c = 0.7;.and with float declaration with one decimal point the code doesnt work properly.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not “their own code”. Unlike the code in the question, the code in this answer prints `It Should be here` for any compiler that rightfully defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to zero, although interestingly it does not have to for a compiler that rightfully defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to 2.

Comment: I have changed my code!!

Comment: It is not a good idea to compare with a value (like the value 0.7 in our case) because you never know the machine’s approximation for a variable assignment! (in that case the approximation was 0.699999988079071044921875)